Charge distribution SAR ADC: derivation of voltage on comparator for first charge redistribution step
I want to understand SAR (Successive-approximation) ADCs based on the charge redistribution principle as described e.g. in this Application note
Unfortunately, I don´t get it. So I drawer down my thoughts and hope someone can find my misconceptions.

It starts by charging a capacitor bank of parallel capacitors to input voltage Vin

Everything is clear in this stage, all the caps in parallel give a total capacitance of 2C.



Then, switches change position so that the comparator sees the negative VIN, because essentially only the position of the GND reference is swapped by the switches.


So, this is also clear to me, the comparator sees -VIN at this stage


For determining the first (MSB) bit, the switch at the capacitor corresponding to the most significant bit switches. And there we are. How can one derive that the voltage at the input of the comparator now is given by -VIN +VREF/2 ?


I beg to NOT only state "this is a capacitive voltage divider and the voltages add". No - this is not a technical explanation. I am searching for a bullet-proof derivation in terms of EE.
I have outlined my thoughts in handwritten form, which you can see below. As you can see, my derivation results in something similar than the formula stated in all the app notes, but nowhere, a thorough explanation or derivation was given. I would like to know what is wrong in the calculations below.





I beg to NOT only state "this is a capacitive voltage divider and the voltages add". No - this is not a technical explanation.

Interestingly enough, this is a very technical explanation of exactly what is going on! Hopefully the below will convince you of that.

For determining the first (MSB) bit, the switch at the capacitor corresponding to the most significant bit switches. And there we are. How can one derive that the voltage at the input of the comparator now is given by -VIN +VREF/2 ?

The states progress from A, to B, to C.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
First, observe that C1=C2 in the ADC schematic.
A. -V(C1)=V(C2)=V1
B. V(T) = V(C1)+V(C2) = -V1+V1 = 0
C. V(T) transitions from 0V to Vref.
It is the state C where all the interesting things happen.

V(T)=0. Vref is attached.

V(T) goes from 0V to Vref. A current must flow to recharge the capacitors to this new voltage.

A current flows through the capacitors in series. Same current flows through both capacitors. I(C1)=I(C2), I(C1)Δt=I(C2)Δt, thus ΔQ(C1)=ΔQ(C2).

ΔQ(C1)=ΔQ(C2), and since C1=C2, recall C=ΔQ/ΔV, thus ΔV(C1)=ΔV(C2).

Vref = ΔV(T) = ΔV(C1)+ΔV(C2), and since ΔV(C1)=ΔV(C2) thus Vref  = 2ΔV(C1) = 2ΔV(C2), and thus Vref/2 = ΔV(C1) = ΔV(C2).

At the start of C, we had V(C2)=-Vin. At the end of C, V(C2)=-Vin+ΔV(C2) = -Vin + Vref/2.


And we're done.
The key observation is that if we have two equal capacitances in series and the voltage is changed across this series-connected pair, the change of voltage on each capacitor is the same, and they must add to the external change of voltage.
All that we had to do is to "see" that we in fact have just two capacitances in series, in spite of the big mess of the original schematic.
And this was exactly your argument.

Unfortunately, I don´t get it.

I dare to disagree. You do get it!

I would like to know what is wrong in the calculations below.

Nothing at all.

nowhere a thorough explanation or derivation was given

Because capacitive voltage dividers are just as basic as resistive voltage dividers. The app notes would get really, really long if this had to be explained ad nauseam. Where would you stop? The notes must assume some level of expertise. They are not meant to be introductory teaching materials - well, except some of the best app notes out there by well known authors :) They target a practicing engineer, who presumably was educated, and can look back into notes or textbooks or online or whatever to quickly refresh what they may have forgotten but is relevant to the understanding of the app note.

Tweaked Falstad simulation will help this explanation.
Whatever the source does, the charges that enter or leave the upper cap also have to enter/leave on the second cap, because the caps are in series.
Is this correct?
Yes.  KVL must be satisfied.
My explanation will be a little drawn out to explain the process.
$$Q_{End} =  C_{Total} V_{Ref}$$
Let's take an actual voltage 5.6V with C = 16nF and a 8V reference (LSB = 0.25V) on a 5-bit SAR.
Sample Mode. All switches are closed so:
\$Q = V_{In} \ 2C = 5.6V \times 2 \times 16nF = 179.2nC\$

Hold Mode. SB is connected to reference voltage (8V). SA is opened.  S4 to S0 and S0* are connected to ground.  Comparator sees -5.6V.

Now the fun starts.  First step is fairly straight forward since C = C, which means \$Q_{Upper} = Q_{Lower}\$, and we will add 8V of charge.
MSB. S4 is connected to reference voltage.

This connects \$C_{Upper}\$ in series with \$C_{Lower}\$.  \$Q_{Upper} = Q_{Lower} = \frac {179.2nC}{2} = 89.6nC\$ and \$Q_{Net} = 0\$. Upper capacitor cancels out lower capacitor.
$$Q_{Ref} = V_{Ref} \ \frac {C} {2} = 8V \times \frac {16nF}{2} = 64nC$$
$$Q_{Upper} = 89.6nC + 64nC = 153.6nC$$
$$V_{Upper} = \frac {153.6nC}{16nF} = 9.6V$$
$$Q_{Lower} = -89.6nC + 64nC = -25.6nC$$
$$V_{Lower} = \frac {-25.6nC}{16nF} = -1.6V$$
KVL is satisfied.  9.6V - 1.6V = 8V.  We have added 64nC of charge to both capacitors.
If comparator voltage is less than 0, we store a 1.  5.6V is greater than 4V, so we keep the MSB.  This keeps S4 on.  S3 is closed.
Now it gets a tad messy.

Half the charge of the lower capacitor gets switched to upper.
We look at existing charges on capacitors.
$$Q_{Upper} = 153.6nC + \frac {25.6nC}{2} = 166.4nC$$
$$V_{Upper} = \frac {166.4nC}{24nF} = 6.933V$$
$$Q_{Lower} = \frac {-25.6nC}{2} = -12.8nC$$
$$V_{Lower} = \frac {-12.8nC}{8nF} = -1.6V$$
Now impact of refereence voltage.
KVL 8V - (6.933V - 1.6V) = 2.667V applied to 24nF s 8nF = 6nF.
$$Q_{Ref} = 2.667V \times 6nF = 16nC$$
$$Q_{Upper} = 166.4nC + 16nC = 182.4nC$$
$$V_{Upper} = \frac {182.4nC}{24nF} = 7.6V$$
$$Q_{Lower} = -12.8nC + 16nC = 3.2nC$$
$$V_{Lower} = \frac {3.2nC}{8nF} = 0.4V$$
You are correct, each cap does change it's voltage by ΔV, or more specifically ΔQ.
If you look at charge instead of voltage, it will correct your issue which has to do with polarity.

This is wrong. \$C_{Upper}\$ has \$+V_{In}\$ and \$C_{Lower}\$ has \$-V_{In}\$, so \$V_{Net} = 0\$ and \$Q_{Net} = 0\$.

Yes, but opposite in polarity.

Nope. You are ignoring the fact that the capacitors are opposite in polarity and cancel each other out.  KVL must be satisfied.

Hmm, you say: CUpper has +VIn .. this is what I cannot argue. The caps where in parallel in step 1 and are then jaut disconnected and rearranged. Why should the polarity change on the upper capacitor?

You have polarities and arrows on your drawing correct, but $-V_{In} $ is incorrect.  It does not agree with arrow or polarities.  That makes KVL wrong. We will be adding $V_{Ref}/2 $ to each capacitor.

If we charge up 2C of capacitance to 5.6V during Sample.  Flip it to get -5.6V during Hold. MSB puts C in series with parallel C, splitting charge.  Upper C is again + and lower C -.
